# input value is not changing instead it add a letter to object and delete old data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, create-react-app, onchange

I want to add user input and add handleChange event to add its value in an empty object.
here is the code

```
function SignUp() {
    const userDetails = {
        displayName: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: ''
    }
    const [state, setState] = useState(userDetails);
    const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = userDetails;
    
    const handleChange = event => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setState({ ...state, [name]: value });
    }
 console.log(userDetails);
 return (
 <form className='sign-up-form'>
                    <FormInput
                        type='text'
                        name='displayName'
                        value={displayName}
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                        label='Display Name'
                        required />
 <CustonButton type='submit'>SIGN UP</CustonButton>
 </form>
 )
}
```

here is the problem - whever i type something in input field it dont show anything and in console it shows only one last letter i type.

i tried changing setState method but it didnt work

```
setState(
            state => ({ ...state, [name]: value })
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `FormInput`'s value you are referencing the wrong variable.

Try to change that line:

```
const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = userDetails;
```

into:

```
const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = state;
```

to actually utilize the (modified) state.